# How to wait for a button event in a separate form

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

So I have form Foo, and form Bar. Assuming i've made a Bar object, initialized it and shown it:

```
Bar b = new Bar();
b.Show();
```

Bar has a button. I need to use an event, that when pushed, will trigger some code in Foo. I cant create a new object of Foo from inside Bar, since there's already active variables and such.

Any ideas?

EDIT:
An easier way to do it, would be to stop the code after b.Show(), then wait till the called window executes this.Close(); Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Pass the instance of `Foo` to `Bar`

Comment: How would i do that? Create an internal Foo object then ass it as a param?

Comment: your question is incomplete..what are you trying to do..from where are you calling show on `bar`..

Comment: An easier way to do it, would be to stop the code after b.Show(), then wait till the called window executes this.Close();

Is there a way to do that?

Comment: @Anirudh If implemented properly you don't need to know or care.

Comment: All the three answers are correct, but if I have to choose I would go for Event handler. It's more elegant and doesn't interfere with Form's usual construction. I always avoid adding a new constructor if such a solution is available.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you [mentioned in comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17730220/how-to-wait-for-a-button-event-in-a-separate-form/17730319#comment25845618_17730220) the `Bar` is a form that is being closed when the button is clicked you can simply use the existing `FormClosed` event rather than defining your own:

```
Bar b = new Bar();
b.Show();
b.FormClosed += (s, args) => DoStuff();
```

If you want to do some action when the button is clicked and it doesn't so happen that the form is being closed at the same time then you can define a custom event in `Bar`, which can be done like so:

```
public class Bar
{
    public event Action MyButtonClicked;
}
```

Then fire that event when the button is clicked:

```
public void buttonClicked(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
    if(MyButtonClicked != null) MyButtonClicked();
}
```

Then `Foo` can subscribe to that event:

```
Bar b = new Bar();
b.Show();
b.MyButtonClicked += () => DoStuff();
```

Comment: Sweet, thanks man. I ended up using the FormClosed function, since i didnt even know that existed! Thankyou thankyou thankyou!

Answer (score 5):

Declare a new event in `Bar`:

```
public event EventHandler SomethingHappened;

private void OnSomethingHappened()
{
    var handler = SomethingHappened;
    if (handler != null)
        handler(this, EventArgs.Empty);
}
```

And trigger it in the event handler for the button:

```
private void TheButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    OnSomethingHappened();
}
```

In `Foo`, subscribe to the event:

```
Bar b = new Bar();
b.SomethingHappened += Bar_SomethingHappened;
b.Show();

...

void Bar_SomethingHappened(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Do whatever you need to do...
}
```

This approach is better than passing an instance of `Foo` to `Bar`, because this way `Bar` doesn't have to know anything about `Foo`, so it reduces coupling. Also, you can more easily reuse `Bar` from another form.

Comment: +1 for highlighing `so it reduces coupling` + `you can more easily reuse Bar`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use composition

```
public class Bar
{
  private Foo f; 
  public Bar(Foo value)
  {
    f = value;
  } 

}

Foo f = new Foo(); 
Bar b = new Bar(f);
```

In your event in Bar, call `f.Method()`